# Check if checkbox is checked and alert "Hi"

Tags: javascript

So I have a dropdown list with checkboxes.

```
<div id = "dropdown" class ="dropdown">
   <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label
       <span class="text-space>Item 1</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
      <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label
       <span class="text-space>Item 2</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label
       <span class="text-space>Item 3</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label
       <span class="text-space>Item 4</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label
       <span class="text-space>Item 5</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label
       <span class="text-space>Item 6</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to check if checkbox is checked and just simple text "Hi".
But it doesn't work. I am not sure but I am trying to get all inputs with type="checkbox" and for each checkbox addEventListener on click.

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            alert("Hi")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/knoam32g/1/. I wonder if you have alert/popups disabled in your browser? Replace the alert with a `console.log("clicked")`

Comment: Your HTML is syntactically invalid. There are missing `>` characters after `label`.

Comment: good catch @tromgy Fixed here: https://jsfiddle.net/knoam32g/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener for the `change` event. It triggers whenever a checkbox is checked and unchecked. Use `this.checked` to verify if the checkbox is checked or not. Note that it is safe to use `this` keyword here because the function in `addEventListener` is a regular function and not an arrow function.

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            console.log(`Hi from Checkbox #${i + 1}`);
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdown" class="dropdown">
   <div class="dropdown-row">
     <label>
       <span class="text-space">Item 1</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
      <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label>
       <span class="text-space">Item 2</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label>
       <span class="text-space">Item 3</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label>
       <span class="text-space">Item 4</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label>
       <span class="text-space">Item 5</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
   <div class = "dropdown-row">
     <label>
       <span class="text-space">Item 6</span>
       <input type="checkbox" class="clickable">
     </label>
   </div>
</div>
```